# Can writing "inform" come out as impolite when addressing a superior?

Tags: professionalism, email, language, email-etiquette

If I am writing in email to a superior that I would like to tell him or her something, should I write ‘I would like to inform you about something’ or ‘I would like to let you know something’?

Is using ‘inform’ impolite to the superior?

Comment: Need a country tag. In Australia, 'inform' work be borderline impolite because it's very formal. It would make the email seem overly official. It would be better to say "let you know". I know it's a bit weird that being formal is seen as impolite. https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/30603/rudeness-by-being-polite for a bit more information.

Comment: Thank you. I now understand that 'inform' is a bit impolite. It seems to me that the receivers of the email may think they are given something but given no choice and has to accept the email. That's why I have the above question. I actually feel uncomfortable in using 'inform' in writing.

Comment: That is my understanding too. Though I admit there may be cultural aspects at play, so you may want to wait for other comments/answers (and provide a country tag) to make sure.

Comment: There is no need for either, you can just inform them without saying you want to inform them.... or you can use what everyone else uses which is 'For your info(rmation)'

Comment: Yes, I think 'For your info' is also a good alternative. Thank you.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie well, in case OP want's to convey an important or official message, then being formal would be the way to go... it seems that this depends a bit more on the message rather than the locale or context.

Comment: @DarkCygnus Absolutely. If it has to be an official email it probably makes sense to use more formal language.

Comment: Or even the abbreviation FYI: we are out of coffee filters

Comment: One further question. Can I write to my superior "I would like to let you know that we only have something..."?

Answer (score 3):

I would say that it's not so much the specific word "inform" that is formal, but the whole phrase "I would like to inform you".

It's the sort of introduction that is normally used when reporting misconduct, making a complaint, or even drawing something to someone's attention when the implication is that they should already have been aware.

There would be absolutely nothing wrong with saying something like "John informs me that the Xmas party is on the Xth of December".

But "I would like to inform you that the coffee machine is out of filters" (to adopt DarkCygnus's example) sounds a bit narky, even if you're talking to the coffee machine man himself.

"Just to let you know" is probably the best introduction for fire-and-forget type notifications in the workplace, although if the information is expected to be unwelcome then it might do to soften it even further (exactly how to do so being dependent on context).

Comment: A further question: Can I write to my superior  'I would like to let you know that we have two quotations...'?

Comment: @Alan, it all depends on context. For example, if it is simply a progress report on a project your superior is already familiar with, then just say "Reporting progress on Project X, the quotation from Smith's came in yesterday and we now have two quotations".

Answer (score 3):

It depends upon context.  If you are informing them that you are out of coffee filters or will be out of the office next Tuesday, then a simple FYI is fine.  If you are telling someone that they didn’t get a raise or when resigning “I regret to inform you” is more appropriate.

Anecdotal, but the first thing that comes to my mind when hearing the word inform is military/police informing the next of kin of the death of a family member.  Second thing would be college admissions “We are pleased to inform you that you have been accepted”.  Inform is formal and serious.

Answer (score 1):

> Is using ‘inform’ impolite to the superior?

Hardly, unless it's a very locale-specific preference not to use 'inform'.

As long as it is clear what you are saying, there can be many phrasing variations that are ok to use.

Worth mentioning that using "inform" will give the email a more formal tone, though, so if you are wanting to convey a more casual message then perhaps consider using a more relaxed term.

Anyways, you can also go more directly to the point, and make your statement/email briefer.

For example, instead of writing this:

> Good morning [xx], I would like to inform you about something. Today, I noticed that we ran out of coffee filters. Should I go buy some? Thanks, Alan

You could:

> Good morning [xx]. I see that we ran out of coffee filters. Should I go buy some? Thanks, Alan.

Comment: @BigMadAndy indeed. Enhancing the suggested phrasing :)